# Как получить все значения из формы?

Tags: javascript

Можно относительно удобно получить значение input-от из формы, если мы знаем name каждого в отдельности input. А существует ли относительно простой способ получить значение любых input из формы, имею ввиду нативными средствами.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');

const submit = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.currentTarget.name.value);
  console.log(e.currentTarget.name2.value);
  console.log(e.currentTarget.name3.value);
  console.log(e.currentTarget.values); // ??
}
form.addEventListener('submit', submit)
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <input name="name" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input name="name2" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input name="name3" />
  </div>
  <button>GO</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');

const submit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData(form);
  for(let pair of formData.entries()) {
     console.log(pair); // где pair - это массив вида [name, value]
  }
}
form.addEventListener('submit', submit)
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <input name="name" value="1" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input name="name2" value="2" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input name="name3" value="3" />
  </div>
  <button>GO</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Думаю правильнее было бы  `const formData = new FormData(e.currentTarget);`

Answer (score 1):

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');

const submit = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.currentTarget.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(function(field){
    console.log(field.name+"="+field.value);
  });
}
form.addEventListener('submit', submit)
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <input name="name" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input name="name2" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input name="name3" />
  </div>
  <button>GO</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Все поля с атрибутом name, доступны по их имени или индексу. Так же у элемента form есть свойство [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/length)

Поэтому пройтись по всем значимым элементам можно с помощью простого цикла:

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');

const submit = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  for (var i = 0; i < e.currentTarget.length; i++) {
    console.log(e.currentTarget[i].value);
  }
}
form.addEventListener('submit', submit)
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <input name="name" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input name="name2" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input name="name3" />
  </div>
  <button>GO</button>
</form>
```